# Should I filtering my data for d3 in SQL or JS

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, filtering, d3.js

I've been contemplating this question as a develop visualizations for large sets of data in my mySQL database.

My current code runs a php SQL query when the page loads, converts it to JSON, and stores it in a Javascript variable for later use by d3 to visualize.

During visualization, I need to use that data, but also filter out results or perform some sort of quanitizing or binning.

Is it better to run multiple SQL queries in php as the page loads and store the results into multiple Javascript variables (hence letting SQL do the work)

or...

Do I continue what I'm doing, and run through the data in Javascript with for loops, pulling out the filtered data I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL to do the work it should make for a more responsive app and is the "right" place for it IMO. Data layer as opposed to presentation layer sort of thing.

Comment: So what if a control on the UI requires some filtering, such as a slider to crop data or filter out results.  Would it be more beneficial to fire off an ajax query, receive the response later on, and then refresh the data with the new ajax result?

Comment: A good question; I think this starts to take you into the tricky area of balancing UI responsiveness areas against one another - a long initial load with faster "data tweak" response time, vs fast initial load, and short delays as you re-load different data scopes. My answer would be: it depends. Design the UI where possible such that it's clear whether controls are minor filters to already-loaded data, or substantial reload operations. Bear in mind possible client limits too, e.g. slow PCs with little RAM may not handle such large data?

Answer (score 0):

You might check out [crossfilter.js](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) and [dc.js](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/).

Both of these libraries do the filtering on the client side using highly optimized Javascript, and let you quickly create interactive filter-based dashboards.